# How to find the closest lat and long in a text file?

Tags: r

I have a text file contains information as follows:

```
   Grid Point Index, Latitude, Longitude, Cell
 167,    0.000000,    9.432301, 1350
 169,    0.000000,    9.544590, 1350
 171,    0.000000,    9.656878, 1350
 173,    0.000000,    9.769168, 1350
 175,    0.000000,    9.881457, 1350
 177,    0.000000,    9.993747, 1350
 179,    0.000000,   10.106036, 1386
 181,    0.000000,   10.218326, 1386
```

I would like to find out the corresponding Grid point and cell for this lat and long
:0.000000,   11.902665.
well, I can do it manually  but this will take lots of the time.
It is sure that there is no exact coordinate corresponds to my input, so I want the closest ones in the file to the input.
Can anybody help me to build this function

```
   insert lat and long
```

then will find the closest lat-long in the file and the corresponding grid point index  and cell

to read the file

```
      das= read.table("C:\\Users\\lonlatnter.txt", sep=",",header=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`gdist` function from Imap package calculates [Great-circle distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance). Try this:

```
install.packages("Imap")
library("Imap")

#Dummy data
dat <- read.table(text="   Grid Point Index, Latitude, Longitude, Cell
 167,    0.000000,    9.432301, 1350
 169,    0.000000,    9.544590, 1350
 171,    0.000000,    9.656878, 1350
 173,    0.000000,    9.769168, 1350
 175,    0.000000,    9.881457, 1350
 177,    0.000000,    9.993747, 1350
 179,    0.000000,   10.106036, 1386
 181,    0.000000,   10.218326, 1386", header=T, sep=",")

#MyPoint
myLatitude <- 0.000000 
myLongitude <- 11.902665

#gdist Geodesic distance (great circle distance) between points
dat$Dist <- gdist(lat.1=dat$Latitude,
                       lon.1=dat$Longitude,
                       lat.2=myLatitude,
                       lon.2=myLongitude)

#Output the shortest distance - Min
dat[dat$Dist == min(dat$Dist),]

#Output
#   Grid.Point.Index Latitude Longitude Cell     Dist
#8              181        0  10.21833 1386 101.2418
```

Comment: Thanks! We don't find the same result...I guess because google Maps is computing distance by `mode = c("driving", "walking", "bicycling")` and you by bird flying....So I think you answer is the right one. +1

Comment: @agstudy We still don't know if the OP wants to fly like a bird, take a walk, drive, or cycle :)

Comment: @sacvf check your typos, you are assigning `dat` to `das` dataframe. In my example I used only `dat` dataframe.

Answer (score 4):

very simple, but not 100% precise (earth is not flat :-) ):

```
df <- read.table(text="   Grid Point Index, Latitude, Longitude, Cell
 167,    0.000000,    9.432301, 1350
 169,    0.000000,    9.544590, 1350
 171,    0.000000,    9.656878, 1350
 173,    0.000000,    9.769168, 1350
 175,    0.000000,    9.881457, 1350
 177,    0.000000,    9.993747, 1350
 179,    0.000000,   10.106036, 1386
 181,    0.000000,   10.218326, 1386", header=T, sep=",")


findGrid <- function(lat, lon){
  index <- which.min(sqrt((df$Latitude-lat)^2+(df$Longitude-lon)^2))
  df$Grid.Point.Index[index]
}

> findGrid(0,9.9)
[1] 175
> findGrid(0,9.7)
[1] 171
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use, `ggmap` and `mapdist` which Compute map distances using **Google Maps**.

```
library(ggmap)
origin <- revgeocode(c( 11.902665,0.000000))
do.call(rbind,apply(DT,1,function(x){
  end <- revgeocode(c(x['Longitude'],x['Latitude']))
  mapdist(from=origin,to=end)[,c('from','to','km')]
  }))
```

We have a smart result with locations name (notlat/long) with distance in km.

```
        from                       to      km
1 R14, Gabon       Komo-Mondah, Gabon      NA
2 R14, Gabon       Komo-Mondah, Gabon      NA
3 R14, Gabon       Komo-Mondah, Gabon      NA
4 R14, Gabon       Komo-Mondah, Gabon      NA
5 R14, Gabon              Komo, Gabon 324.206
6 R14, Gabon                N1, Gabon 281.145
7 R14, Gabon N1, Ekouk Village, Gabon 304.186
8 R14, Gabon          N1, Oyan, Gabon 308.246
```

I don't know why it is giving some NA. But if We omit this detail :) the nearset point is :

```
res [which.min(res$km),]
 from        to      km
6 R14, Gabon N1, Gabon 281.145
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
data = read.table("C:\\Users\\lonlatnter.txt", sep=",",header=TRUE)

distance = function(Latitude, Longitude,x,y)
{
    sqrt((Latitude-y)^2+(Longitude-x)^2)
}
nearby <- function(y,x)
{
    dist= (with(data,distance(Latitude, Longitude,x,y)))
    data[match(min(dist),dist),]
}

nearby(0,9.6)

# Grid.Point.Index Latitude Longitude Cell
# 2              169        0   9.54459 1350
```